# ERRORLEVEL of a FINDSTR command always returning 0

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to remove an entry in the hosts file on some devices. The `FINDSTR` command is working, but always returning `errorlevel` `0`.

I know that by default, the `%errorlevel%` is *always* `0`.
So if the previous command is not setting the error code it will always return `0`.

I basically need to find a string in the hosts file, if it exists it should save a new hosts file without the line containing the string.

This is what I do:

```
set HOSTSFILE=%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
set TEMP_HOSTS=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%__hosts

FINDSTR /V /I /C:"string to search for" "%HOSTSFILE%" > "%TEMP_HOSTS%"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 COPY /b/v/y "%TEMP_HOSTS%" "%HOSTSFILE%"
```

This basically works. However, the above code will *always* return `errorlevel` `0` and thus *always* copy over the hosts file, even if the string is not present in the file.

I know it doesn't really matter, but I'm curious as to why the `errorlevel` is not working here?
The `errorlevel` should be set by the previous command, which in this case is the `FINDSTR`.

I've also tried with the `FIND` command and with `!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%`.

Comment: This shows your assertion is wrong. `findstr /c:fonts c:\windows\win.ini > "%userprofile%\desktop\tttt.txt"`
 `Echo %errorlevel%`
 `findstr /c:cat c:\windows\win.ini > "%userprofile%\desktop\tttt.txt"`
 `Echo %errorlevel%`
 `pause`

Comment: Sorry but It is working as intended. `findstr` sets the `errorlevel` when it does not find any line that matches the indicated conditions. You are requesting everything except (`/v`) one (or more) line(s) so if there is any other line inside the file then `findstr` will find it and the `errorlevel` will be `0` as there are lines matching the condition.

Comment: Why not create a backup of `hosts` along side the current then run `Find` against the backup redirected to the current. This way you'll always have a backup regardless of whether a change was made. `CD /D "%__AppDir__%drivers\etc" && (Copy /Y "hosts" "hosts.bak") && (Find /I /V "string to search for"<"hosts.bak">"hosts")`.

Comment: in other words: you are asking "is there any line that does not contain the search string" - which is successful, if there is at least one of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot test for 0 before you test for greater values.

First, you can omit `EQU` operator and use special form `IF ERRORLEVEL value` `command`.

Second `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` actually means `IF ERRORLEVEL >= 0`.

This is documented after you run command `help if` from the command line:

```
 ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
                   returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
                   specified.
```

`findstr` command can return ERRORLEVEL values **0**, **1**, and **2**.

Based on the above, to handle them properly, you need to write tests in descending order.

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 ...
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ...
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 ...
```

If you are satisfied with somewhat incorrect, but mostly functioning handling, write at least:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO stringNotFound
command(s) if value is 0
:stringNotFound
```

This ignores [return value **2**](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) (syntax error), but that one should never occur with a constant expression in a tested script.

If you want to learn more, running `help if` from the command line is a good place to start.